# When I call an API on My First Page I want to fire Second Page API at the same time how can I achieve it! | React Native

Tags: react-native

I am working on react native from 3 months means I am still a beginner ,Help me with this Functionality : What I want is that when I add a product to my shopping cart the cart number on my bottom tab should increase at the same time . How can I achieve it?

This is my add to cart screen Here I am adding my products to the cart

```
import {
    View, Text, StyleSheet, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity, Alert, Image, ActivityIndicator, Dimensions
} from 'react-native'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'
import Octicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Octicons'
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'
import AntDesign from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign';
import ImageZoom from 'react-native-image-pan-zoom';
import { UserProvider } from './UserContext'

const AddProduct = ({ route, navigation }) => {

    const [count, setCount] = useState(1)
    console.log("this is item quantity=>", count);

    const prodId = route.params.prodId
    console.log('data is coming from route', prodId);

    const [prodImg, setProdImg] = useState("")
    console.log("this is product image from use state=>", prodImg);
    const [productName, setProductName] = useState("")
    const [productDesc, setProductDesc] = useState("")
    // const [in_stock, setIn_stock] = useState("")
    const [availableQty, setAvailableQty] = useState("")
    const [basePrice, setBasePrice] = useState("")
    const [variations, setVariations] = useState([])
    console.log("this is variation data", variations);
    const [changePrice, setChangePrice] = useState("")
    const [variationid, setVariationid] = useState("")
    console.log('this is variation id=>', variationid);

    const [selectedVar, setselectedVar] = useState(0)
    const [customerId, setCustomerId] = useState("")
    console.log("This is customer id ", customerId);
    const baseUrl = "https://team.flymingotech.in/azamDeals/public/"
    const [loader, setLoader] = useState(false)
    const GetProductById = () => {
        setLoader(true)
        var requestOptions = {
            method: 'GET',
            redirect: 'follow'
        };

        fetch(`https://team.flymingotech.in/azamDeals/public/api/readByID/${route.params.prodId}/read`, requestOptions)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(result => {
                console.log(result)
                setProdImg(result[0].data.product_images)
                setProductName(result[0].data.product_name)
                setProductDesc(result[0].data.product_desc)
                setAvailableQty(result[0].data.available_qty)
                setBasePrice(result[0].data.base_price)
                // setProductData(result.data)
                setVariations(result[0].data?.variations)
                // if (result && result.data) {
                //     setVariations(result.data.variations);
                //   } else {
                //     console.log('Could not retrieve data');
                //   }
                setLoader(false)

            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('error in getProductbyId api', error)
                setLoader(false)
            });
    }
    const getId = async () => {
        try {
            const customer_id = JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem("Customer_id"))
            console.log("this is getting async storage data", customer_id);
            setCustomerId(customer_id)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        getId()
        GetProductById()
    }, [route.params.prodId])
    function increment() {
        //setCount(prevCount => prevCount+=1);
        setCount(function (prevCount) {
            return (prevCount += 1);
        });
    }
    function decrement() {
        setCount(function (prevCount) {
            if (prevCount > 0) {
                return (prevCount -= 1);
            } else {
                return (prevCount = 0);
            }
        });
    }

    const AddCart = async () => {
        if (variationid == 0) {
            Alert.alert("Please select the product variation")
            return false;
        } else if (count == 0) {
            Alert.alert("Qty cannot be 0")
        }
        else {
            var myHeaders = new Headers();
            myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

            var raw = JSON.stringify({
                "product_id": prodId,
                "item_qty": count,
                "item_price": changePrice,
                "total_price": "",
                "c_id": customerId,
                "variation_id": variationid
            });

            var requestOptions = {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: myHeaders,
                body: raw,
                redirect: 'follow'
            };

            await fetch("https://team.flymingotech.in/azamDeals/public/api/new_cart", requestOptions)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(result => {
                    console.log(result)
                    if (result.status == 1) {
                        Alert.alert('Added to cart')
                    }

                })
                .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
        }
    }
    const onSelect = (id) => {
        setselectedVar(id)
        console.log(id);
    }
    const images = [
        {
            url:
                'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AboutReact/sampleresource/master/sample_img.png',
        },
        {
            url:
                'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AboutReact/sampleresource/master/old_logo.png',
        },
    ];
    
    return (
        <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
            <View style={{ height: 80, backgroundColor: '#006C32', flexDirection: 'row', paddingTop: 25 }}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>
                    <AntDesign style={{ paddingLeft: 20 }} name='arrowleft' size={30} color="white" />
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <Text style={{ paddingLeft: 20, fontSize: 20, color: 'white' }}>Product Detail</Text>
            </View>
            {/* <SearchHeader /> */}
            {loader ?
                <View style={{
                    alignItems: "center",
                    justifyContent: "center",
                    height: "90%"
                }}>
                    <ActivityIndicator size={50} color="green" />
                </View>
                :

                <ScrollView>
                    <View style={{ marginLeft: 15, marginRight: 15 }}>
                        <View>

                            {/* <Image style={{ height: 300, width: '100%', borderRadius: 10, marginTop: 10 }}
                                source={{ uri: prodImg }} /> */}
                            <ImageZoom
                                cropWidth={350}
                                cropHeight={300}
                                imageWidth={200}
                                imageHeight={200}>
                                <Image style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }}
                                    source={{ uri: prodImg }} />
                            </ImageZoom>
                            <Text style={{ color: 'black', fontWeight: 'bold', marginTop: 10 }}>{productName}</Text>
                            <Text style={{ color: 'black', backgroundColor: 'white' }}>{productDesc}</Text>
                            <Text style={{ color: 'black', backgroundColor: 'white' }}  >Stock:{availableQty}</Text>
                            <Text style={{ color: 'black', backgroundColor: 'white' }}  >Base Price:₹{basePrice}</Text>
                            <Text style={{ color: 'black', backgroundColor: 'white' }}  >Variation Price:₹{changePrice}</Text>
                            {/* <Text style={{ color: 'black', backgroundColor: 'white' }}  >Variationid:{variationid}</Text>  */}

                            <View style={{ marginTop: 14 }}>
                                <Text style={{ color: 'black', fontSize: 18, }}>Size</Text>
                                <View style={{
                                    flexDirection: 'row',
                                    justifyContent: 'space-around', height: 25
                                }}>
                                    {/* {console.log("type", productData.variations.length)} */}
                                    <View >
                                        {variations?.length > 0 && variations.map((item, i) => (
                                            <View key={i}>
                                                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setChangePrice(item.variation_price,) | setVariationid(item.id) |onSelect(item.id)} style={{
                                                    height: 70, width: 120,
                                                    borderWidth: 0.5, borderColor: 'grey', borderRadius: 10,
                                                    justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center',
                                                    backgroundColor: selectedVar === item.id ? "lightgrey" : "#fff"
                                                }}>
                                                    <Text style={{ color: 'black',  }}>{item.variation_label}</Text>
                                                    <Text style={{ color: 'black',  }}>{item.variation_weight}</Text>
                                                </TouchableOpacity>
                                            </View>
                                        ))}
                                    </View>
                                    {/* <FlatList horizontal
                                    data={productData}
                                    renderItem={(item)=>renderItem(item)}
                                    /> */}



                                    {/* <Pressable onPress={() => getSize('s')} style={[styles.variable, { backgroundColor: size === 's' ? '#D1D1D1' : '#FFF' }]}><Text style={styles.variableValue}>S</Text></Pressable>
                                <Pressable onPress={() => getSize('m')} style={[styles.variable, { backgroundColor: size === 'm' ? '#D1D1D1' : '#FFF' }]}><Text style={styles.variableValue}>M</Text></Pressable>
                                <Pressable onPress={() => getSize('l')} style={[styles.variable, { backgroundColor: size === 'l' ? '#D1D1D1' : '#FFF' }]}><Text style={styles.variableValue}>L</Text></Pressable> */}

                                </View>
                            </View>
                            <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", marginTop: 50, justifyContent: 'space-between', paddingBottom: 10 }}>
                                <View style={styles.countButton}>
                                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={decrement} style={{ alignSelf: 'center', marginLeft: 5 }}>
                                        <Octicons name="dash" size={28} color="black" />
                                    </TouchableOpacity>
                                    <Text style={{ alignSelf: 'center', fontSize: 17, marginLeft: 4, color: 'black' }}>{count}</Text>
                                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={increment} style={{ alignSelf: 'center' }}>
                                        <Ionicons name="add" size={28} color="black" />
                                    </TouchableOpacity>
                                </View>
                                <TouchableOpacity onPress={AddCart} style={{
                                    backgroundColor: '#006C32', height: 40
                                    , justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', width: 150, borderRadius: 5,
                                }}>
                                    <Text style={{ color: 'white', fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Add to Cart</Text>
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                            </View>

                            {/* <View>
                            <TouchableOpacity style={{
                                width: 300, marginTop: 20, backgroundColor: 'darkgreen', height: 50
                                , borderRadius: 10, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', alignSelf: 'center'
                            }}>
                                <Text style={{ color: 'white', fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Buy Now</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View> */}
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </ScrollView>
            }
        </View>
    )
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    mainContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'white'
    },
    image: {
        height: 300, width: '100%',
    },
    countButton: {
        backgroundColor: 'white', height: 40, borderWidth: 0.5, borderColor: 'grey'
        , width: 100, flexDirection: 'row', borderRadius: 10, justifyContent: 'space-between',

    },
    variable: {
        padding: 5,
        color: 'black',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#999999',
        borderRadius: 4,
    },
    variableValue: {

        fontWeight: '700',
    },
})

export default AddProduct
```

And this is my screen where I am showing the count of the products as a badge using an API it is working it is showing the data but when I refresh the app that time only it shows the count

```
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute } from '@react-navigation/native';
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'
import User from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome'

// screens
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack'
import Home from '../screens/HomeScreen/Home';
import { CustomerStack, Cart, Profile } from './CustomerStack';
import { Badge } from 'react-native-elements';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

// Screen Names

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const BottomTabNav = ({ route, navigation }) => {
    const [Count, setCount] = useState("")
    console.log("this is Count of cart=>",Count);
    useEffect(() => {
        getCartCount()
    }, [])
    const getCartCount = async () => {
        const customer_id = JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem("Customer_id"))
        var requestOptions = {
            method: 'GET',
            redirect: 'follow'
        };

        fetch(`https://team.flymingotech.in/azamDeals/public/api/countCartItems/${customer_id}`, requestOptions)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(result => {
                console.log(result)
                setCount(result.data)
            })
            .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
    }
    <Tab.Screen
        name="CustomerStack"
        component={CustomerStack}
        options={({ route }) => ({ tabBarStyle: getTabBarStyle(route) })} />


    const getTabBarStyle = (route) => {
        const routeName = getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute(route) ?? 'CustomerStack';
        let display = (routeName === 'Player') ? 'none' : 'flex';
        return { display }
    }
    return (

        <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName='CustomerStack'
            tabBarOptions={{
                // activeTintColor: 'red',
                inactiveTintColor: 'white',

            }}
            screenOptions={({ route, }) => ({
                tabBarStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: '#006C32',
                },

                tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
                    let iconName;
                    let rn = route.name;
                    if (rn === "CustomDrawer") {
                        iconName = focused ? 'home' : 'home'
                    }
                    else if (rn === "CustomerStack") {
                        iconName = focused ? 'home' : 'home'
                    }

                    else if (rn === "Cart") {
                        <View style={styles.unreadBadge}>
                            <Text style={styles.unreadBadgeText}>11</Text>
                        </View>
                        iconName = focused ? 'shopping-cart' : 'shopping-cart'

                    } else if (rn === "Account") {
                        iconName = focused ? 'user' : 'user'
                    }
                    return <User name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />
                },
            })}>
            <Tab.Screen options={{ headerShown: false, tabBarActiveTintColor: 'white', }} name="CustomerStack" component={CustomerStack} />

            <Tab.Screen options={{
                headerShown: false, tabBarActiveTintColor: 'white',
                tabBarBadge: Count
            }} name="Cart" component={Cart} />
            <Tab.Screen options={{ headerShown: false, tabBarActiveTintColor: 'white', }} name="Account" component={Profile} />

        </Tab.Navigator>

    )

}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    unreadBadge: {
        backgroundColor: '#FF3250',
        position: 'absolute',
        left: 20,
        bottom: 18,
        width: 25,
        height: 18,
        borderradius: 25,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        zIndex: 100,    // this one is used to put message notify on top of icon
    },
    unreadBadgeText: {
        color: 'white',
        fontWeight: '600',
    },
})

export default BottomTabNav
```

What I was going to try is that keep calling that API every 5 seconds then after calling the API So many times it will give Too many request error .

Whether I should use UseContext or Pass data through both the screen and call API I don't get it!

> 

Comment: you can use redux may be this will help you https://redux.js.org/

Comment: if you don't undersatnd let me know

Comment: ok I will check the redux on google and youtube if I can't do it I will help!